# error in embeding images in mail through javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is my code for sending mail to the user using javax.mail.1.5.2. I need to attach some images. I used servetcontext getRealPath for this. But it is saying that ServletContextEvent variable sce (see code) needs to be initialized. There is something which am missing. Here is my code.

```
public void sendSSLMessage(String recipients[], String subject,
                String htmlText, String from , MailSSLSocketFactory sf) throws MessagingException {
            boolean debug = true;
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
                     {
                         protected PasswordAuthentication                   

                      getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new   
                         PasswordAuthentication("support@jiffie.in", "support@1234$");
                        }
                    });

            session.setDebug(debug);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            /*Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);*/
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            message.setFrom(addressFrom);

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part  (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            ServletContextEvent sce; 
            ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext(); //this shows error. sce may not have been initialized
            String contextPath = context.getRealPath("/");
            //...
            File contextDir = new File(contextPath);
            File emailImage = new File(contextDir, "img/logo.png");
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(emailImage );
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<logo>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // Setting the Subject and Content Type
            message.setSubject(subject);

            Transport.send(message);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, clean up your code by fixing all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

sce just appears in the middle of your program without ever being assigned a value, that's why it's complaining about not being initialized.  But really, if you just want the ServletContext, get rid of sce and use the javax.servlet.ServletRequest method getServletContext().  But you'll need to pass in the "request" object from the Servlet where you're calling this method.